# How template and layout called by a controller magento?

Tags: magento

What is the procedure of calling layout and template in magento when a controller is called ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions which are responsible for calling the layout and render the layout.

Basically, we define layout file in `config.xml`

```
 <layout>
            <updates>
                <custommodule>
                    <file>custommodule.xml</file>
                </custommodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
```

- See more at: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/#sthash.iXApjrG0.dpuf

At controller ,layout is loaded using function  `$this->loadLayout()`  then `$this->renderLayout()` function render the layout

Comment: Deeper on magento request flow through this image :  http://www.amicontech.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/page-request-flow.png or even more deeperer request flow here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7762/666